# MySQL query not efficient (PHP search)

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I want to show the user, how many calls he made by country prefix.

I need to combine the results by country (since every country code has many sub-codes for cities/regions)

My current query takes 80 seconds to complete, 
on top of that the query runs again for pagination purposes,
and another query for the total amount of calls/time.

This is a very heavy DB (1gb+) every search can take a couple of minutes to complete and I wonder if I can make it more reasonable.

Here's a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4e2f3/4)

queries:

```
SELECT 
  sec_to_time(avg(t1.sessiontime)) as aloc,
  CONCAT(TRUNCATE(sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) * 100 /   count(*),1),'%') as asr,
  count(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) as calls,
  cast(t4.countryprefix as unsigned) as prefix,
  t4.countryname as destination,
  SEC_TO_TIME(sum(t1.sessiontime)) as duration
FROM
  cc_call AS t1
    inner join
  cc_prefix as t2 ON t1.destination = t2.prefix
    inner join
  cc_country as t4 ON t1.destination like CONCAT(t4.countryprefix, '%')
WHERE
  t1.card_id = '97' AND t1.starttime >= ('2013-04-1')
group by t4.countryprefix
order by duration DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

The idea here is to iterate over all cc_country prefixes, and see if they match 'destination' in cc_call using LIKE.
Again, this is a very big DB, is there a better way to perform this query?

Comment: Did you try `Explain Plan` and see which part of the query is slowing down?

Comment: Another hackey way is to remove on of the columns in the select query and try if it makes it faster. Likewise, try with all the columns and the conditions as well to see which part of the query is slowing down

Comment: Is there any way you could extract the countryprefix from the destination and store it seperately? I expect this would speed up the join (you could then join on two fixed length int fields for example) and therefore the whole query massively.

Comment: @KevinRave Never used 'Explain Plan', I removed all but count() from select - same result, even removed the inner join of cc_prefix - same result. I guess it may be the LIKE clause in the third join ?

Comment: @Markus403 I may not change the existing DB, nor add columns to the tables. You're idea is to get rid of the LIKE and just match prefixes ?

Comment: Yes! And btw isn't the first join (`t2 on`...) destroying the result you want? I think you need there again `like CONCAT(t2.prefix, '%')`

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns used in LIKE. If not, add indexes, that will greatly reduce the time.

Comment: @Markus403 yes actually the t2 was unneeded, how can I achieve that, I mean removing the LIKE? as I said Im unable to change or add tables to the DB -/

Comment: @KevinRave No index on cc_country, as you can see on the fiddle -/

Comment: Your date format looks wrong as well;  '2013-04-1' is not same as '2013-04-01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one solution to get rid of the `like` is this:

```
SELECT 
    avg(t1.sessiontime) as aloc,
    CONCAT(TRUNCATE(sum(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) * 100 / count(*),1),'%') as asr,
    count(t1.terminatecauseid = 1) as calls,
    t4.countryprefix as prefix,
    t4.countryname as destination,
    sum(t1.sessiontime) as duration
FROM
    cc_call AS t1
        inner join
    cc_country as t4 ON left(t1.destination,length(t4.countryprefix)) = t4.countryprefix
WHERE
    t1.card_id = '97' AND t1.starttime >= ('2013-04-1')
GROUP by t4.countryprefix
ORDER by duration DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

I also added an index on destination and countryprefix to possibly speed up the join.

If the changes I made really have an effect on your query with the data you have has to be tried out by you.

Additionally you got the SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f01ec/2).

And some usefull information about Query optimizing [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855).

Comment: For some reason your query takes 15 secs longer, Ill accept your answer for the additional links about Query optimization, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. have you tried just adding the index and keeping the like? The problem is still that you have to split the destination first before you are able to join on it - no wonder it has poor performance. My solution was just another way to achieve that... apparently not a better way.

Comment: btw I just found a problem that again strongly implicates you need to split the country prefix from the destination: have a look at [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1aa9/7). The last 3 rows you have the call with id `13902512` twice.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli are you aware of this problem I described?

Comment: could you please explain again what the problem is and where? thank you

Comment: @NitsanBaleli As you can see in the fiddle linked in one of my comments before, with the current join you would join the countryprefix `1` and `1345` to the destination `134567` therefore you get two entries in the result for one call. I doubt that that's the behavior you want.

Comment: could you suggest of a better way?

Comment: With the current database it's not possible in my opinion, except you know how long the part without a countryprefix of the destination is (fixed length) and therefore know if the countryprefix is 1 digit or 4 digits out of the total length of the destination. Then you could split the destination and join the first part of it on the unique countryprefix.